# Strategies for keeping a .NET alt-tab replacement responsive after a long period of non-use?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm working on a simple alt-tab replacement program.  It's implemented in C# as a hidden WPF window that's brought to the foreground by a global keyboard hotkey.

For the most part this works great, and the application window appears immediately after the hotkey is pressed.  However, if it has been a long time since the user has activated the window, it can be slow in "spinning up," and take 3-5 seconds to appear.  I assume it has something to do with Windows paging app's memory to disk.

Are there any good strategies for keeping the application responsive after long periods of inactivity?

(Since it's open source, you can look at the [full code](http://bitbucket.org/jasulak/switcheroo/src), if it helps.)

Comment: if you run the app at higher priority (just changing it in taskmgr) does that keep the behavior from happening?  I don't remember for sure whether the process and/or thread priority are considered by the VM for paging out, but I think it is (since presumably, the added latency hit is less tolerable for those processes)

Comment: That's an interesting idea, and I'll give it a try, but I've noticed that other "always available" programs like Slickrun and Winsplit Revolution run at normal thread priority.

Comment: I think maybe another process - like a service or other executable that runs at startup - and interacts with the alt-tab replacement app periodically to keep it from being swapped out.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a timer in your code that fires once every minute, and in that timer tick handler, execute some code. This should keep your process "active".